# What is the difference between the "unzip" and "extract" tags?

Tags: support, tags

I understand that [unzip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unzip) is referring to decompressing a file that has been previously compressed, but I don't understand the difference between [unzip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unzip), and [extract](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extract), considering also that, for example, [Batch the "Extract Here" command](https://superuser.com/questions/328328/batch-the-extract-here-command) uses both.

When should [extract](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extract) be used?

Comment: I would think [extract] is more generic, while [unzip] refers explicitly to taking something out of a zip file. For [extract] you can have a question like extracting frames from a video and such kind of problems.

Comment: _Unzip_ doesn't refer to .zip files in a particular way: "_Computing_ decompress (a file) that has previously been compressed." It is like _google_, which doesn't necessary means "searching with Google."

Comment: *Zip file* doesn't refer to .zip files in a particular way. :)

Comment: I'd vote to close as duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/392468/is-unzip-the-same-as-extract) if I could. Merging them sounds a lot like what Psycogeek would recommend: "Combining `extract` and `zip` or `rar` or `tar` makes `unzip`, `unrar`, and `untar` unnecessary!" Not sure where the cutoff should be. I don't think we need to act here.